# Laravel 5.2 route model binding

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

Laravel has a documentation regarding route model binding which could be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding). But there is no example with regards to this kind of scenario:

```
Route::get('search/', 'ArticleController@search');
```

How to I implicitly bind a model into the route? I know I could do something like this directly on the controller's method.

```
public function search(Model $model) {
    // some code here
}
```

But I'm just curious on how to do it on the routes instead.

I am after this approach

```
Route::get('search/{article}', function(ArticlesModel $articlesModel) {
    // this should be calling 'ArticleController@search'
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to call the `ArticleController@search` from the route closure when you can just have a route definition that calls it automatically like @Jeff showed in his answer?

Comment: if your model is ArticlesModel try updating the route to be 'search/{ArticlesModel}' and then when you go GET /search/1 it will try to bind an ArticleModel with ID of 1

Comment: Ok I updated my answer but I agree with @Bogdan it doesn't make sense to do this at all.  Passing `"ArticleController@search"` just does it for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your variable is called `$model`, Laravel will look for a wildcard segment of the url written as `{model}`:

In routes.php:

```
Route::get('search/{article}', 'ArticleController@search');
```

In controller:

```
function search(Article $article) {
    //$article is the Article with the id from {article}, ie. articles/2 is article 2
}
```

Edit... the way that you are suggesting doesn't really make sense.  That would just be an extra step that is skipped entirely by just using `"ArticleController@search"`.  I think this code would function although I don't recommend it:

```
Route::get('search/{article}', function(Article $article)
{
    $controller = App::make(ArticleController::class);
    return App::call([$controller, 'search'], compact('article'));
}
```

Comment: But where is the part that it will call the search method from the ArticleController?

Comment: I have updated my question wherein I am after a certain approach.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. I just wonder how to return a controller's method thru a callback from the routes. If your first given answer would suffice, then I'd go for that. Just wanted to know ways or fall backs in case.

Answer (score 0):

routes.php

```
Route::get('search/{article}', 'ArticleController@search');
```

ArticleController.php

```
public function search(Model $article) {
    // some code here
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question wherein I am after a certain approach.