# Model binding in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to fetch data from database in Laravel using Model binding in Controller but it returns empty $task array instead

here is my routes.php :

```
<?php

Route::get('/tasks','TasksController@index');
Route::get('/tasks/{task}','TasksController@show');
```

and this the TasksController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Task;

class TasksController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Task $task)
    {
        return $task;
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you querying your url? `/tasks/1` 1 being the id of the task?

Comment: also when you go to /tasks what does that spit out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.2 route model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565170/laravel-5-2-route-model-binding)

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: Please add your `function index()` to your question also.

Comment: What's the primary key of `Task`?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Route::get('/tasks/{id}','TasksController@show');
```

in route model binding you can pass the id in the route and handle it in the show function

```
 public function show($id)
 {
    $task = Task::find($id);
    return $task;
 }
```

This will directly return the task

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing other code it's hard to answer however your `function index()` should look similar to this:

```
 public function index(Task $task)
    {
        $tasks = $task->all();

        return view('page', compact('tasks'));
    }
```

Now, assuming you're gathering the ID's via a foreach loop your controller code should look like this:

```
 public function show($id, Task $task)
    {
        $task = $task->find($id);

        return view('somePage', compact('task'));
    }
```

This will then pass `$task` back to a page of your choosing to display the specific task you are getting.

Your Routing is fine providing you're passing the:

`<a href="/tasks/{{ $task->id}}">Something</a>`

back within the blade.